How do you suppress "Reference isn't Valid" display when hyperlink points to worksheet named with boolean title "true" or "false"
`I have a worksheet with all the hidden sheets listed as hyperlinks.  All of them work flawlessly except if the name is "true" or "false"... then the "Reference Isn't Valid" error pops up, and after you close it, goes right to the worksheet.  It has nothing to do with the worksheet being hidden, because all the others work fine... I am assuming that it is being seen as a "boolean" connection.
        application.displayalerts  = false
doesn't work, nor does another suggestion I found somewhere else...
`CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").RegWrite _               "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & _
"\Common\Security\DisableHyperlinkWarning", 1, "REG_DWORD"`

Frustrating. Anyone have an answer to this?
This is the private code within "ThisWorkbook" that controls the hyperlink:
`    Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As    Hyperlink)
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").RegWrite _
"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version _ &    "\Common\Security\DisableHyperlinkWarning", 1, _ "REG_DWORD"
On Error Resume Next
Select Case UCase$(Sh.Name)
Case "TOPIC INDEX"
If Left(Target.SubAddress, 1) = "'" Then
 LinkTo = Mid(Target.SubAddress, 2, Len(Target.SubAddress) _ - 5) & "!A1"
Else: LinkTo = Target.SubAddress
End If
TopicSheet = InStr(1, LinkTo, "!")
If TopicSheet > 0 Then
   MySheet = Left(LinkTo, TopicSheet - 1)
   Worksheets(MySheet).Visible = True
   Worksheets(MySheet).Select
   MyAddr = Mid(LinkTo, TopicSheet + 1)
   Worksheets(MySheet).Range(MyAddr).Select
End If
Case Else
Worksheets("Topic Index").Select
Sh.Visible = False
End Select

CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").RegWrite _
"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & _     "\Common\Security\DisableHyperlinkWarning", 0, _ "REG_DWORD"
End Sub``

